# Android: Open a PDF file and goto page X

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, sdk

I'm looking for a way to open a PDF File and directly show the user a specific page.

So I have a pdf and I know that I want to show e.g. page 6.

As far as I know there is no third party app that accepts an intent like this.

I'm not sure if a PDF SDK could solve my problem.

Does anyone have experience with this topic?

Thanks,

Percy

Comment: Maybe this api can help you http://www.mupdf.com/

Comment: This might be helpful, thanks!

Comment: by providing a "page" extra in the opening Intent, both ezpdf-reader and lirbi-reader can help you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no app providing that feature.

If you don't find a third-party app that can accept that kind f request, then you have to do your own PDF viewer...